# configure kubectl to provision minikube localy instead of Kubernetes cluster in aws (AWS EKS)

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, kubernetes

I have Minikube installed on my laptop and I have a Kubernetes cluster on AWS EKS

After creating a cluster on AWS I received a command to execute so that my `kubectl` command manages the cluster on AWS.

However I want to manage my Minikube on my laptop now and when I execute `kubectl` command it manages the cluster on AWS.

How can I setup `kubectl` to manage the Minikube on my laptop ?

This was the command I had to execute to make `kubectl`  to manage cluster on AWS

`aws eks update-kubeconfig --name testclusterCluster00507BD3-639846f8ec5241a69f54eabd38c730a0 --region us-east-1 --role-arn arn:aws:iam::xxx:role/CdkStack-testclusterClusterMastersRoleAAD0ED84-DR14A5TYS195`

And this is some output from commands to see current state

```
tomas@ubuntu20:~/.kube$ kubectl config current-context

arn:aws:eks:eu-west-2:5555:cluster/kubernetescluster5B555-555e74

tomas@ubuntu20:~/.kube$ kubectl config get-clusters
NAME
minikube
arn:aws:eks:eu-west-2:5555:cluster/kubernetescluster5B555-555e74

tomas@ubuntu20:~/.kube$ kubectl config get-users
NAME
arn:aws:eks:eu-west-2:5555:cluster/kubernetescluster5B555-555e74
minikube
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do some reading about that [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/organize-cluster-access-kubeconfig/) and [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/configure-access-multiple-clusters/)

But to keep it short : "By default, the `kubectl` command-line tool uses parameters from the current context (an element in a kubeconfig file) to communicate with the cluster."

To find out current-context :

```
tomas@ubuntu20:~$ kubectl config current-context
arn:aws:eks:eu-west-2:5555:cluster/kubernetescluster5B555-555e74
```

To find out available contexts :

```
tomas@ubuntu20:~$ kubectl config get-contexts

CURRENT   NAME                   CLUSTER                   AUTHINFO           NAMESPACE
*         arn:aws:...55-555e74  arn:aws:...55-555e74    arn:aws:...55-555e74
          minikube              minikube                 minikube              default
```

To change the current-context and to manage the cluster associated with it :

```
tomas@ubuntu20:~$ kubectl config use-context minikube
Switched to context "minikube".
```